# What justification was there for Russell and Wittgenstein to posit 'atomism'?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-language, semantics, atomism

In light of the history of philosophy's recognition that the scientific method appeared to be becoming a type of role model for the other 'natural' sciences and thus that obtaining to objective proof for any given hypothesis is a requirement to substantiate any claim, what basis in the history of philosophy did R and W refer to in their claim that 'kernels' of language contained some sort of agency (atomism) when it is somewhat obvious that language can never rise above the level of semiotics? e.g. As a book sits on a shelf it conveys no meaning, even if it is picked up and the pages are flipped through. Only a human mind can bring its information alive, and therefore meaning only occurs within the confines of the individual mind.

Everything is up to interpretation; data, measurements, and qualia . Which makes Wittgenstein's assertion, 'the world is made of facts', an absurd proposition.

Be sure to support your opinion with reference to what was the source, historically, of their claim to 'atomism'.

Comment: The “model” was the recently discovered predicate locic language, were “basic” sentences have the form “name-predicate” or “name-relation-name”.

Comment: See SEP’s entry on Analysis for discussion about Frege’s and Moore’s and Russell’s views and contributions to “logical analysis”

Comment: Wow, this question — if a question is what it really is — has so much topspin it's making me a bit dizzy. When I try to factor out all of the things claimed as true, false, absurd, obvious, or etc, I'm not at all certain what's left. Could you maybe edit things so that we can see the *question* without the interference of all that editorializing?

Comment: The thrust of the question seems a bit like asking for the justification of Rutherford for providing such an obviously false theory of atoms. Philosophy of language made the turn you take as the starting point only after and because of late Wittgenstein, ie. about 35-40 years later on. Pierce's work did not get much attention until the 1960s.

Comment: @Mauro AlLLEGRANZA- Thanks. Your response is very much in line with the question. The difference lies in that predication is simply giving assent or mental affirmation to the 'inherence' of a particular quality in a subject (or object or thing in the sensible world). It is at quite a remove from W/R's assigning some 'occult' agency to the 'roots' of words. Can you direct me to that SEP entry you mentioned? Regards,

Comment: @Philip Hocking- Thanks and yes 'late' Wittgenstein made some useful observations about common language. At the same time it seems that certain blatant errors get washed over when certain thinkers tend to become glorified in the history. As philosophers we have a responsibility to remember the mistakes which clouded the picture and egotistically misled many followers. It's an important aspect as long it does not become Wittgenstein bashing.

Comment: [Analysis in Frege, Russell, etc](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analysis/s6.html)

Comment: Firstly, your comments show that there is no genuine *question* here. Secondly, the shortcomings of W's early philosophy of language are all too well-known in the philosophical community and to late W as well. There is no glorification. R, Whitehead and early W are rightfully hailed for their contributions to logic and the insistence that there is such a thing as the nonsense of not well-formed sentences. That philosophy of language (well, most of it) took a pragmatic turn, later on, has nothing to do with that. The comment reads like misplaced zealotry, TBH.

Comment: The point of "*the world is the totality of facts, not of things*" is exactly that facts are over and above things, the result of human mind interacting with things, logical atoms being the smallest units of such interaction. In other words, he is making the same point as you do, see [Wittgenstein on facts and objects](https://www3.nd.edu/~jspeaks/courses/2007-8/43904/_HANDOUTS/wittgenstein-facts-objects.pdf). Logical atomism oversimplified the relation between facts and things, but it never made absurd propositions you ascribe to it, it was about the world as known to us.

Comment: Thanks @conifold, very helpful. If you'd submitted this as an answer I would have accepted it. Cheers,

Comment: See also [Russell’s Logical Atomism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-atomism) as well as [Wittgenstein’s Logical Atomism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-atomism/). The first one, in particular, gives a detailed account of "justification adduced by Russell to posit 'logical atomism'."

Comment: Besides SEP, [WP has a more general overview of atomism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_atomism) and the works that undergird it. It's a deeply embedded notion in Western philosophy that there exists an objective reality independent of psychological construction. [Antipsychologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-psychologism) and logical-positivism are other examples of philosophers trying to preserve naive realism and ascribe normativism to objective reality. Both positions failed...

Comment: Since you're interested, progressve sciences and linguistics actually affirm your intuition that truth, one form of information, is as all normativity is , a construct of the embodied mind. As an alternative to the still popular [truth-conditional semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics), see [cognitive semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_linguistics) whose program aims to show how truth is really a byproduct of the value-laden mind.

Comment: Whenever I read the statements like, 'both positions failed', it reminds me of E. E. Harris's contention that 'analytical philosophy failed before it began.' Statements which one serves up to insult another person's intelligence are not useful or helpful. Not to mention that they suggest that whoever speaks them considers themselves omniscient and an all-seeing judge.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders With all do respect, when the founders of a program, as in the case of the logical empiricism and positivism, admit that their program fails to achieve it's intellectual objectives, it's not unreasonable for those who admire and study them (read me), to characterize it as such. As for the failure of antipsychologism, the idea that math exists independently of the brain-mind is essentially dead in analytical philosophy. There are indeed hold outs who cling to some form of Platonic idealism, but I've never come across a cognitive scientist who advocates such a position...

Comment: Again, I would suggest your objection to my characterization is an emotional one, and not one rooted in semantic consistency. I do respect your repeated defenses of your beliefs and their subsequent cultivation in the face of direct and copious criticism. Most people throw in the towel on the thinking game quickly.

Comment: Thanks J D. I'm enjoying myself immensely and trying to awaken a sleepwalking lot is jolly good exercise! Regards, as always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of "the world is the totality of facts, not of things" is exactly that facts are over and above things, the result of human mind interacting with things, logical atoms being the smallest units of such interaction. In other words, he is making the same point as the OP, see [Wittgenstein on facts and objects:  the metaphysics oftheTractatus by Speaks](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ejspeaks/courses/2007-8/43904/_HANDOUTS/wittgenstein-facts-objects.pdf). Logical atomism oversimplified the relation between facts and things, but it never made absurd propositions about projecting facts into objects, it was about the world as known to us:"*The facts in logical space are the world*" T, 1.13:

> "*When Wittgenstein says "1.1 The world is the totality of facts, not of things." he is not denying that there are things, in addition to facts.  Rather, he’s saying that the totality of facts is something over and above the collection of things; even if we are given the totality of things, this does not yet determine the totality of facts.*"

Russell wrote something similar in Logical Atomism (1924), although, unlike Wittgenstein, he included properties and relations in addition to objects as things that "*we express*" by facts:

> "*I want you to realize that when I speak of a fact I do not mean a particular existing thing, such as Socrates or the rain or the sun. Socrates himself does not render any statement true or false.  What I call a fact is the sort of thing that is expressed by a whole sentence, not by a single name like ‘Socrates’. We express a fact, for example, when we say that a certain thing has a certain property, or that it has a certain relation to another thing; but the thing which has the property or the relation is not what I call a ‘fact’.*"

Comment: 'Rendering something true or false', assumes that the law of the excluded middle is an axiomatic universal truth, when all it is is a synthetic/ artificial construct meant to act as a tool for making sweeping value judgements.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders Why LEM? He does not say there that it must be "rendered" one way or the other, only that it does not get "rendered" without our involvement.

Comment: 'Facts' are represented by words which are formed in the 'imagination'. This means that any given proposition will always be a subjective construction which will have nearly infinite numbers of interpretations. When Wittgenstein abandoned the Tractatus it marked the admission of the failure of the analytic method. Why else would there be so many lists and isms which continue to proliferate as each 'new' offshoot falls short and requires another 'new' iteration? It marks an endless regression which never gains any traction. Sorry to be so blunt.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders We do communicate, and "*there is a way of grasping a rule which is not an interpretation*", so regress terminates. PI still follows a version of "analytic method", presumably, so it was not wedded to logical atomism. But how is this related to the original question or LEM?  And why even bother with logical atomism that both Russell and Wittgenstein abandoned?

Comment: Not sure about your quotes but,  'grasping a rule', sounds like one of those Kantian, 'well class we need a rule here so let me invent one' devices. Atomism and LEM , with its desire to satisfy someone's need for a simple world of, it's either black or white, or, true or false, or, right or wrong, both are part and parcel of those simplistic theories which attempt to remove the nuance, complexity and vitality from philosophy and make it into type of puzzle for the not yet mature intellect to play with.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders The quote is from PI §201, see [Wittgenstein on following a Rule](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20115972). And it seems like the opposite of removing nuance and complexity, the traditional regress of interpretations in rule-following was the simplistic trap that many prior rationalists fell into, including earlier Wittgenstein himself.

Comment: @Conifold- Thanks for taking the time to make the reference. I will look forward to reading it. Meanwhile, in the simplest sense, when anyone makes reference to a rule it entails a metaphysical assertion which by necessity must in some measure be a priori and therefore the mind that entertains this 'rule' must engage in an act of agency which can only be described and understood as a product of reasoned understanding. Cheersb

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two books, one which is a list of noun phrases, the other a list of sentences using those nouns. E.g.,

**Horse, moon, jumping, avocados, the prime number the horse thought of, the prime number that comes after the other...**

**The horse is jumping over the moon, counting the number of avocados it sees, which is the prime number before 23.**

As per Quine, if a fact is a "sentence-like slice of reality," then the world is more like the second book. As per Kant, *because* the mind imposes logical forms, then in forming the image of a world-book, the mind represents the world with logical (transyntactic) structure, i.e. according to the model of the book of sentences.

Comment: If you think about it carefully, assuming that a human mind shapes reality is the ultimate hubristic arrogance.

Comment: The word "reality" is shaped by the human mind. At any rate, one doesn't have to invoke only human minds but minds in general. A presumption that the mind ought to be like an eye, a passive observer, not only is unrealistic about how eyes work, after all, but about how minds work, too.

Comment: I am not referring to a word but rather to the scope of human experience. My point is that examining 'words' is an empty exercise. Words, sentences, facts, data, they are all abstractions which Spinoza termed 'aids to the imagination'. They are pointers or signs, not explicaters in themselves.

Comment: Facts and data are no such thing. Positing a structure in objects, corresponding to the form of sentences, is not an explanation, but a precursor to explanation (which will assume a sentential character). Pseudopsychological diagnosis of "ultimate hubris" for such a reason is itself false modesty

Comment: Could not agree more. But there is a stark difference from positing that the mind is an 'agent' and active participant in actuality and the claim that the mind somehow 'shapes' reality. Reality or ontology is prior to human body and mind.